# Why Instruments report a leak?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone app. Instruments reported a leaked object ServiceTypes. Below is the relevant code. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
ServiceTypes *serviceTypes = [[ServiceTypes alloc] init];

if ([userConnection getServiceTypes:serviceTypes]) {
    if ([serviceTypes.types length] > 0) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[serviceTypes.types componentsSeparatedByString: SERVICE_TYPE_DELIMITOR]];
        serviceRequestTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
        [array release];
    }
}

[[self typesTableView] reloadData];
[serviceTypes release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `serviceTypes` is being leaked. From the code you posted, `serviceTypes` is always released at the end of the method, and it doesn't appear to be `retain`ed anywhere in your sample. My question is: what happens inside `getServiceTypes:`. Does that method retain the `serviceTypes` parameter?

One more thing. If `serviceRequestTypes` is an instance variable (and it looks like it is), then you may be leaking memory by reassigning it without releasing the existing `serviceRequestTypes` object first. You should either rewrite `serviceRequestTypes` to be a property and use a synthesized accessor or make sure to release it every time before assigning. If its current value is `nil`, no big deal; the `release` message will simply be ignored. For example:

```
[serviceRequestTypes release];
serviceRequestTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[serviceTypes.types componentsSeparatedByString:SERVICE_TYPE_DELIMITER]];
```